# Linking to a library using qmake in Linux

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

Previously, I have been compiling with Qt Creator by using cmake. I am now keen to learn about qmake and how the `.pro` file should differ to the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Previously, in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, I had the following to enabling linking to a library (PCL):

```
find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
target_link_libraries (pcl-visualizer ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

If I am going to use qmake instead of cmake, what do I need to add to the `.pro` file to enabling linking to this library?

Comment: Does the library support pkg-config? That would be the easiest. Are you using Windows or Linux? Do you need to make it cross-platform or Linux is enough?

Comment: Also, where exactly have you installed it to? Why not the new "shiny" QBS rather than qmake? Not sure about QBS, but qmake is relatively primitive about finding things around if it does not support pkg-config. :-) Please provide all the specific details, otherwise your question will be one of those `use the LIBS variable properly with -l and -L` that have been asked on Stack Overflow many times. I would build PCL myself to see, but it takes me ages. ^_^

Comment: Well, I downloaded PCL using aptitude, so that suggests it might support pkg-config right? If so, how does that help me?

Comment: Try `packagesExist(foo) { CONFIG += link_pkgconfig PKGCONFIG += foo}` where foo is the pcl, libpcl or something similar. Check for an installed .pc file.

Comment: Of course, you can also hard code the path if the library is not in a standard location, but that is not so cool... Having said that, what exactly is the library name that you are trying to link against and where is it installed on your machine?

Comment: Well, actually I do not know the name of the library or where it is. This is the issue I am having. All I did was downloaded the package from aptitude, and then I have been given the above lines for a CMakeLists.txt file. This compiles fine. But I do not know how to find the actual paths of these libraries, or indeed which libraries I actually need, for use with qmake.

Comment: Use aptitude/dpkg to figure it out. Alternatively, you can check what the cmake system is using.

Comment: What command do I actually need to run for dpkg to display the library locations? As for cmake, in CMakeLists.txt, I also have the lines `find_package (PCL 1.7.1 REQUIRED)` and `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (pcl_visualizer ${PCL_LIBRARIES})`. Does this help to identify the name of the libraries needed?

Comment: Well, as long as you do message(${PCL_LIBRARIES}) and let me know the output.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you are asking for. I tried entering `echo ${PCL_LIBRARIES}` into the terminal, but this just returned a blank line. Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: @Karnivaurus, lpapp asked you to use your operating system's tools to display the content of that PCL package you installed. You should answer him; he will then be able to tell you whether it supports package-config or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Qt Creator. open the .pro file, right click somewhere, and select 'Add Library...' The wizard will add all the needed magic to the .pro.

I doubt, however, that switching from cmake to qmake will be beneficial for you.

Comment: The OP did not know where to look for the library, so naturally, he will not be able to add it.